# Why is data access tightly coupled to the Service base in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I'm curious why the decision was made to couple the Service base class in ServiceStack to data access (via the Db property)?  With web services it is very popular to use a Data Repository pattern to fetch the raw data from the database.  These data repositories can be used by many services without having to call a service class.

For example, let's say I am supporting a large retail chain that operates across the nation.  There are a number of settings that will differ across all stores like tax rates.  Each call to one of the web services will need these settings for domain logic.  In a repository pattern I would simply create a data access class whose sole responsibility is to return these settings.  However in ServiceStack I am exposing these settings as a Service (which it needs to be as well).  In my service call the first thing I end up doing is newing up the Setting service and using it inside my other service.  Is this the intention?  Since the services return an object I have to cast the result to the typed service result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack convenience ADO.NET `IDbConnection Db` property allows you to quickly create Database driven services (i.e. the most popular kind) without the overhead and boilerplate of creating a repository if preferred. As ServiceStack Services are already testable and the DTO pattern provides a clean endpoint agnostic Web Service interface, there's often not a lot of value in wrapping and proxying "one-off" data-access into a separate repository.

But at the same time there's nothing forcing you to use the `base.Db` property, (which has no effect if unused). The [Unit Testing Example on the wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Testing#unit-testing) shows an example of using either `base.Db` or Repository pattern:

```
public class SimpleService : Service
{
   public IRockstarRepository RockstarRepository { get; set; }

   public List<Rockstar> Get(FindRockstars request)
   {
      return request.Aged.HasValue
          ? Db.Select<Rockstar>(q => q.Age == request.Aged.Value)
          : Db.Select<Rockstar>();
   }

   public RockstarStatus Get(GetStatus request)
   {
      var rockstar = RockstarRepository.GetByLastName(request.LastName);
      if (rockstar == null)
          throw HttpError.NotFound("'{0}' is no Rockstar".Fmt(request.LastName));

      var status = new RockstarStatus
      {
          Alive = RockstarRepository.IsAlive(request.LastName)
      }.PopulateWith(rockstar); //Populates with matching fields

      return status;
   }
}
```

Note: Returning an `object` or a strong-typed DTO response like `RockstarStatus` have the same effect in ServiceStack, so if preferred you can return a strong typed response and avoid any casting.